# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. Entity Framework 6. Only fails on one table

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-6, primary-key

Please can anyone help with this issue I'm having. I've exhausted the current suggestions on here.

We are rewriting an application in MVC EF6 Codefirst using the existing database structure (SQL 2005).

The SQL Script for the table in question:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblStaff](
[staffID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[firstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[lastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Alias] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[addressID] [int] NULL,
[teamID] [int] NULL,
[managerID] [int] NULL,
[clientID] [int] NULL,
[jobTitle] [int] NULL,
[activeFlag] [bit] NULL,
[contractorID] [int] NULL,
[fullName] [nvarchar](101) NULL,
[securityTrainingDate] [datetime] NULL,
[CRBCheckDate] [datetime] NULL,
[CMSTrainingDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblStaff_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [staffID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)     ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

The Model code in the application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CMS3.Model.DBTables
{

public class tblStaff
{
 //   [ColumnAttribute(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]

    [Key]
    public int staffID { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public int? addressID { get; set; }
    public int? managerID { get; set; }
    public int? clientID { get; set; }
    public int? jobTitle { get; set; }
    public bool? activeFlag { get; set; }
    public int? contractorID { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? securityTrainingDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CRBCheckDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CMSTrainingDate { get; set; }
    public int? teamID { get; set; }

    public virtual tblPlussTeams Team { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("staffID")]
    public ICollection<tblClientSchemeHistory> CaseWorker1Schemes { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("staffID")]
    public ICollection<tblClientSchemeHistory> CaseWorker2Schemes { get; set; }
}
}
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CMS3.Model.DBTables
{
public class tblClientSchemeHistory
{
    [Key]

    public int clientSchemeHistoryID { get; set; }
    public int clientID { get; set; }
    public string SchemeName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? endDate { get; set; }
    public int? wcID { get; set; }
    public string currentModule { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Caseworker1"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int? caseWorker1ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Caseworker2"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public int? caseWorker2ID { get; set; }
    public int? LDID { get; set; }
    public int? MHID { get; set; }
    public int contractTypeID { get; set; }
    public int? FSFID { get; set; }
    public bool? hiddenFlag { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("clientID")]
    public virtual tblClients Client { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("CaseWorker1Schemes")]
    public virtual tblStaff Caseworker1 { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("CaseWorker2Schemes")]
    public virtual tblStaff Caseworker2 { get; set; }
    //public virtual tblClients Client { get; set; }

}
```

}

Within the context we have to define that tblClientSchemeHistory.Caseworker1 and tblClientSchemeHistory.Caseworker2 both map to tblStaff.staffID

EF Context

```
..DbSet<tblStaff> Staff { get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<tblClientSchemeHistory>().HasOptional(b => b.Caseworker1).WithMany(a => a.CaseWorker1Schemes).HasForeignKey(b => b.caseWorker1ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<tblClientSchemeHistory>().HasOptional(b => b.Caseworker2).WithMany(a => a.CaseWorker2Schemes).HasForeignKey(b => b.caseWorker2ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<tblStaff>().HasKey(a => a.staffID);


    }
```

User Repository where the error occurs. When inspecting the newStaffRecord Object, staffID is set to 0, implying the database will deal with indexing the primary key. This exact call works with the same Db using our old application which uses an EDMX Diagram to map relationships.

UserRepository.cs

```
 bool ILoginRepository.CreateUser(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime securityTrainingDate, DateTime cRBCheckDate, DateTime cMSTrainingDate, string password, string email)
    {


        CMS3Context _db = new CMS3Context();
        string salt = null;

        string passwordHash = pwdManager.GeneratePasswordHash(password, out salt);

        var newStaffRecord = new tblStaff()
        {
            firstName = firstName,
            lastName = lastName,
            securityTrainingDate = securityTrainingDate,
            CRBCheckDate = cRBCheckDate,
            CMSTrainingDate = cMSTrainingDate,
            activeFlag = true,
            Alias = "",

            //TODO - these values should come from dropdowns that are fed in to this method
            contractorID = 1,
            teamID = null,
            fullName = firstName + " " + lastName

        };
        _db.Staff.Add(newStaffRecord);

        _db.SaveChanges();

        var newLoginRecord = new tblLogin()
        {
            staffID = 1,
            userName = firstName + "." + lastName,
            active = true,
            password = passwordHash,
            salt = salt,
            passwordChanged = DateTime.Now,
            failedLoginAttempts = 0
        };
        _db.Users.Add(newLoginRecord);
        _db.SaveChanges();


        return (true);
    }
```

Creating new records in different tables using the new application work fine, automatically indexing the PK.

Example of working Insert for tblCMS3Audit

```
USE [CMS3Prototype]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblAuditCMS3]    Script Date: 01/06/2015    14:27:49 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblAuditCMS3](
[auditID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[userName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[session] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[route] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[data] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[ipAddress] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[actionType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_tblAuditCMS3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[auditID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

And AuditRepository

```
bool IAuditRepository.createAuditLine(DateTime time, string userName, string session, string ipAddress, string route, string actionType, string data)
    {
        CMS3Context _db = new CMS3Context();
        var auditLine = new tblAuditCMS3()
        {
            time = time,
            userName = userName,
            session = session,
            ipAddress = ipAddress,
            route = route,
            actionType = actionType,
            data = data

        };
        _db.Audit.Add(auditLine);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return (true);
    }
```

Comment: does the other tables also have an identity column? if the answer is yes, check what is different in the entity framework definitions for this table.

Comment: Thank you for your response Zohar. I already do an insert that works fine. tblAuditCMS3.auditID is a primary key and set as auto-index in the database and everything works fine. I'm new to this CodeFirst methodology, the only mappings I can see are those stated in the CMS3Context.cs file which I posted above. I'm used to viewing the edmx diagram in our previous application, is there something similar that i'm missing here. I thought it builds the equivalent of this at runtime..

Comment: This does not help to answer the question. edit your question to include the working example (both ddl for the table and entity framework objects).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` as an attribute to `public int staffID { get; set; }`

Comment: Hi Macros, I added the above attribute and it now generates a different error  - "A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'staffID'."}

Comment: Your foreign keys don't look correct -  I don't think [ForeignKey("staffID")] should be there and seeing as you are using the fluent API to tie these up, you should be able to remove that line both times it appears in tblStaff